# strange {"OK":{}} response on ElasticSearch curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'

Tags: elasticsearch

On one on my nodes in my ElasticSearch cluster I get the following strange response:

Command:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

Response:

```
{"OK":{}}
```

Not sure what to do about this?  Anyone run into this before?

### UPDATE:

This is what I get when I call (I replaced IP's with xxx):

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_nodes/jvm?human\&pretty

{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "nodes" : {
    "dtUV63D4RBq9JXw_o03-eg" : {
      "name" : "elasticsearch1",
      "transport_address" : "inet[xxx/xxx:9300]",
      "host" : "elasticsearch1",
      "ip" : "xxx",
      "version" : "1.3.2",
      "build" : "dee175d",
      "http_address" : "inet[/xxx:9200]",
      "jvm" : {
        "pid" : 1471,
        "version" : "1.7.0_65",
        "vm_name" : "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM",
        "vm_version" : "24.65-b04",
        "vm_vendor" : "Oracle Corporation",
        "start_time" : "2014-11-19T14:50:10.408Z",
        "start_time_in_millis" : 1416408610408,
        "mem" : {
          "heap_init" : "4gb",
          "heap_init_in_bytes" : 4294967296,
          "heap_max" : "3.9gb",
          "heap_max_in_bytes" : 4277534720,
          "non_heap_init" : "23.1mb",
          "non_heap_init_in_bytes" : 24313856,
          "non_heap_max" : "214mb",
          "non_heap_max_in_bytes" : 224395264,
          "direct_max" : "3.9gb",
          "direct_max_in_bytes" : 4277534720
        },
        "gc_collectors" : [ "ParNew", "ConcurrentMarkSweep" ],
        "memory_pools" : [ "Code Cache", "Par Eden Space", "Par Survivor Space", "CMS Old Gen", "CMS Perm Gen" ]
      }
    },
    "8eGVx6IGQ8qiFTc4rnaG3A" : {
      "name" : "elasticsearch2",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/xxx:9300]",
      "host" : "elasticsearch2",
      "ip" : "xxx",
      "version" : "1.3.2",
      "build" : "dee175d",
      "http_address" : "inet[/xxx:9200]",
      "jvm" : {
        "pid" : 1476,
        "version" : "1.7.0_65",
        "vm_name" : "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM",
        "vm_version" : "24.65-b04",
        "vm_vendor" : "Oracle Corporation",
        "start_time" : "2014-11-19T14:54:33.909Z",
        "start_time_in_millis" : 1416408873909,
        "mem" : {
          "heap_init" : "4gb",
          "heap_init_in_bytes" : 4294967296,
          "heap_max" : "3.9gb",
          "heap_max_in_bytes" : 4277534720,
          "non_heap_init" : "23.1mb",
          "non_heap_init_in_bytes" : 24313856,
          "non_heap_max" : "214mb",
          "non_heap_max_in_bytes" : 224395264,
          "direct_max" : "3.9gb",
          "direct_max_in_bytes" : 4277534720
        },
        "gc_collectors" : [ "ParNew", "ConcurrentMarkSweep" ],
        "memory_pools" : [ "Code Cache", "Par Eden Space", "Par Survivor Space", "CMS Old Gen", "CMS Perm Gen" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm. Which ES version? And are you sure on localhost:9200 you have the ES node?

Comment: I am sure, 1.3.4 I think - I know it is running as I can search it and run kibana on it

Comment: Can you run `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_nodes/jvm?human\&pretty`? What you are seeing is _not_ normal. I took a quick look through the code, and there is _nowhere_ that uses a literal `"OK"` outside of a logging statement.

Comment: @pickypg do get a response form that, see edit

Comment: @slee Is it is possible that your nodes are sitting behind a proxy that hijacked the root request? For example, what happens if you give it `curl -XGET localhost:9200/?pretty`. This should change the formatting of the response a little. PS: As noted in your response, you're running `1.3.2` on both nodes.

Comment: same response {"OK":{}}, don;t think i am behind a proxy as I did get a proper response before.

Comment: If you put `http://localhost:9200` in your browser, what do you get?

Comment: I get the same response

Comment: How about `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health'`?

Comment: And, also, `curl --verbose -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'`

Comment: * Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:9200/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9200 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:9200
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 9
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"OK":{}}

Comment: If, instead of `localhost` you use the actual IP, do you get the same "OK"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elasticsearch 1.3.2 alone is not capable of producing such response - there is simply no `"OK"` string in the production source code. So, I would guess somebody installed a plugin on this node that intercepts some calls and replaces them with this message.

One of the plugins that does that is [elasticsearch-http-basic](https://github.com/Asquera/elasticsearch-http-basic) plugin, which indeed displays `{"OK":{}}` to unauthorized users [instead of a full response](https://github.com/Asquera/elasticsearch-http-basic/blob/36430f74119adeb5ffa26115c8afdf63f44e3e8f/src/main/java/com/asquera/elasticsearch/plugins/http/HttpBasicServer.java#L85). You can verify presence of this and other plugins by executing the following command on the node that gives you responses:

```
curl "localhost:9200/_nodes/plugins?pretty"
```